# ng-click in ng-repeat is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

When I use the parameter hard-coded then `ng-click` works and when pass `item.Id` it is not working, while both renders the same html

```
ng-click="viewHistory(100)"      /// works
ng-click="viewHistory({{item.Id}})"  /// Not working
```

Both render the same html

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" ng-click="viewHistory(100)"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" ng-click="viewHistory(100)"></span>
```

In controller

```
$scope.viewHistory = function (postId) {
    // rest of the code       
};
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: show the `ng-repeat` ... we have no idea where `item.Id` comes from or if `item` has a property `Id`. `Not working` is not a proper problem statement, surely you can provide better troubleshooting information than that

Answer (score 3):

To work `item.id`, your object design should be

```
$scope.items = [{
    id: 1
}, {
    id: 2
}]

$scope.viewHistory = function(postId) {
    // rest of the code       
};
```

Then `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat=" item in items">
  <a ng-click="viewHistory(item.id)"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to use {{}} in parameter

```
ng-click="viewHistory(item.Id)"
```